# First-Order Linear Differential Equation Multiple Choice

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Exercise: If $x(t)$ is a solution of

$$(1-t^2)\mathrm{dx} - tx \mathrm{dt} = \mathrm{dt}$$

and $x(0) = 1,$ then $x\left(\frac12\right)$ is equal to:

**(a)** $\cfrac 2{\sqrt3}\left(\frac \pi{6} + 1\right)\qquad$ 
**(b)** $\cfrac 2{\sqrt3}\left(\frac \pi{6} - 1\right)\qquad$
**(c)** $\cfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt3} \qquad$
**(d)** $\cfrac{\pi}{\sqrt3}$

This is a linear differential equation. On solving, I am getting none of the options.
Option **(a)** is quite close to my answer except $\cfrac{\pi}6$ should be replaced with $\ln\left(\cfrac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)$.

Am I correct? If not what am I missing?

Comment: What work have you done to solve this?  Show your work and people will be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation after applying the integrating factor is
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\sqrt{1-t^2}x(t))=\frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}},~~x(0)=1
\implies
x(t)=\frac{1+\arcsin(t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
$$
so that
$$
x(\tfrac12)=\frac{1+\frac{\pi}6}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}2}
$$
which is indeed choice A.

Comment: @Aryadeva : You forgot the right side. It is $(1-t^2)dx-(tx+1)dt=0$.

Comment: Oh true Thank you +1

Answer (score 0):

$$(1-t^2)dx-txdt=dt$$
$$\sqrt {(1-t^2)}dx-\dfrac {tx}{\sqrt {(1-t^2)}}dt=\dfrac {dt}{\sqrt {(1-t^2)}}$$
Divide both sides by $\sqrt {(1-t^2)}$:
$$\sqrt {(1-t^2)}dx+xd(\sqrt {(1-t^2)})=\dfrac {dt}{\sqrt {(1-t^2)}}$$
$$d(x\sqrt {(1-t^2)})=\dfrac {dt}{\sqrt {(1-t^2)}}$$
Integrate:
$$x\sqrt {(1-t^2)}=\arcsin(t)+C$$
Apply initial condition:
$$x(0)=1 \implies C=1$$
$$x\sqrt {(1-t^2)}=\arcsin(t)+1$$
$$\implies x(1/2)=\dfrac {\pi+6}{3\sqrt {3}}$$